# Required to access the 'request' service, when use HTTP Method Restrictions -phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I am new to Phalcon. Today I had an error, when I tried use the HTTP Method Restrictions.
My router settings are like:

```
$di->setShared('router',function(){
    $router = new Router();

    $router->addPost('/admin_cp/posts/add',[
        'namespace'=>'App\\Backend\\Controllers',
        'controller'=>'post',
        'action'=>'add'
    ]);
    $router->handle();
    return $router;
});
```

But when my app is running, it throws an exception:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Phalcon\Mvc\Router\Exception: A dependency injection container is required to access the 'request'
>   service in phalcon/mvc/router.zep on line 383

And I tried to fix the error with:

```
$di->setShared('request',function(){
    $request = new Request();
    return $request;
});
```

But it still doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

```
$di     = new \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();
$router = new Router(false);
$router->setDI($di);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)